# Should model in iOS MVC contain logic code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, model

I'm working on an app with an Account model (like a credit card or saving account) and i have to check if the Account has permissions to do some action, p.e get the statement.

The Account model has an array of permission enums (Statement = 0, Balance = 1, etc), so i want to know if i can check for the permission on a model method like this.

```
//Inside Account.m

- (BOOL)canDoAction:(AccountPermissionType)permissionType {
  return [self.permissions contains:@permissionType];
}
```

I don't know if i can do that because i've read that the model should not have logic code other than the properties and init.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a class with certain business logic and one of the functions you pass in instance of Account and the permission (or a permission array) you are checking against. Allows for you to implement unit testing against your applications logic to validate expected behavior.